# Regular expression for filtering based on a keyword

Tags: c#, regex, regex-group

I want to filter the string and make groups based on Keyword ('OR', 'AND', 'NOT') etc but excluding the keyword 'OR', 'NOT', 'AND' etc inside the parentheses.

Email=sample@sample.com OR Something =  '(101010101010 OR 0101010123 )' AND Id = \"02341-21236-43497-123234\" AND CreatedDate:[2017-06-20T06:14:11Z TO 2017-07-20T06:14:11Z]

The output groups should be like this:

1. Email=sample@sample.com
2. Something =  (101010101010 OR 0101010123 )
3. Id = "02341-21236-43497-123234"
4. CreatedDate:[2017-06-20T06:14:11Z TO 2017-07-20T06:14:11Z]

Comment: You will probably need to write a parser to handle this.

Comment: So, each one of these three as a match, would that work for you? Or do you actually want them in capturing groups (sub-matches)? Because I don't think the latter is possible.

Comment: Also what flavor or programming language are you using?

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed- I'm using C# and casting them to a match and latter converting them to a list. If I filter on keywords it's going to filter from the parenthese as well. So ends up creating four group items instead of three.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
(?<=^|AND|OR)(?:[^()]+?|.+?\(.+?\).+?)(?=\s*AND|OR|$)
```

[Try it online](https://regex101.com/r/7fEBPB/3).

**Breakdown:**

- `(?<=^|AND|OR)` Assert preceding characters are `AND`, `OR`, or the beginning of the string.
- `(?:` Beginning of a non-capturing group.

  - `[^()]` Matches any character except `(` or `)`.
  - `+?` Matches one or more times of the previous character (lazy match).
  - `|` Or.
  - `.+?` Matches one or more times of any character (lazy match).
  - `\(` Matches the character `(` literally.
  - `.+?` Matches one or more times of any character (lazy match).
  - `\)` Matches the character `)` literally.
  - `.+?` Matches one or more times of any character (lazy match).
- `)` End of the non-capturing group.
- `(?=\s*AND|OR|$)` Assert following characters are `AND`, `OR`, or the end of the string.

**Example of usage in C#:**

```
static List<string> ExtractParts(string input)
{
    string pattern = @"(?<=^|AND|OR)(?:[^()]+?|.+?\(.+?\).+?)(?=\s*AND|OR|$)";
    var matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);

    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    foreach (Match m in matches)
    {
        list.Add(m.Value.Trim());
    }

    return list;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string input = @"Email=sample@sample.com OR " +
                   @"Something = '(101010101010 OR 0101010123 )'" +
                   @" AND Id = \""02341 - 21236 - 43497 - 123234\""";
    List<string> parts = ExtractParts(input);
    foreach (string part in parts)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(part);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

[Live example](http://rextester.com/GBEVNZ88678).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, @Ahmed it does work. I need to learn a lot about Regex now :D

Comment: Glad I was able to help. Just added an explanation of the regex pattern used too.

Comment: Ahh sorry, I forgot to update another field that contains [] brackets. Updated my question. My bad :(

Comment: @AbhishekSingh Actually, it's not about the brackets, I just forget a `?`. Updated.

Comment: Thanks, @Ahmed I'm trying to learn more about Regex. Thanks Again.

Comment: I need a little bit more help in breaking the string if there is a pattern like (SiteId: 5555 AND SiteName: "My New Site"). Basically the current pattern doesn't handle the breaking inside the parentheses if key value pair is present. Thanks!